# AutoDock: MGLTools Python, error list index out of range, using MGL version 1.5.7

Tags: python

I'm an absolute beginner, so I'll try to be elaborate:

I've got MGL version 1.5.7 installed (current latest version),
wanted to save my protein as a .pdbqt format by:
-> file -> read molecule -> protein.pdb -> Grid/Macromolecule/Choose

but it gave me the following error:
[image: IndexError: List index out of range]

IndexError: list index out of range

I saw the question was posted 10 years earlier as well and the answer was that it should have been resolved with the 1.5.6 version, so I don't know how to solve it in my situation. Has anyone else run into this in the current version?
What does the error mean and what can I do about it.

Thanks!

ps. sorry for the awful format

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just solved it: the .pdb file name had a space in it, renamed it, and that seemed to have solved my problem..